# Reusing AssetManager after Disposing it?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am using a assetManager to load various assets. But when I "back button" out of the app and load it again it crashes when reloading the assets again on this line in my `show()` method `while (!Assets.manager.update())`. I get this `FATAL EXCEPTION`

```
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: 
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: 
Cannot run tasks on an executor that has been shutdown (disposed)
```

I get what it means, I disposed the assetManager and thus I cannot perform actions on it. But how would I reload my assets again?

To work around it I can catch the back button and exit the application so it starts fresh again. Or only dispose the `AssetManager` when the user really choses to quit. But I do wonder if there is a option to reinitialize the `AssetManager` somehow.

```
public class Assets {

    public static AssetManager manager = new AssetManager();

    public static final AssetDescriptor<TextureAtlas> spriteAtlas =
            new AssetDescriptor<TextureAtlas>("sprites/sprites.pack", TextureAtlas.class);

    public static final AssetDescriptor<TextureAtlas> uiAtlas =
            new AssetDescriptor<TextureAtlas>("ui/ui.pack", TextureAtlas.class);

    public static final AssetDescriptor<Skin> uiSkin =
            new AssetDescriptor<Skin>("ui/ui.json", Skin.class,
                    new SkinLoader.SkinParameter("ui/ui.pack"));

    public static final AssetDescriptor<BitmapFont> defaultFont =
            new AssetDescriptor<BitmapFont>("ui/default.fnt", BitmapFont.class);

    public static final AssetDescriptor<BitmapFont> mediumFont =
            new AssetDescriptor<BitmapFont>("ui/medium.fnt", BitmapFont.class);

    public static void load()
    {
        manager.load(spriteAtlas);
        manager.load(uiAtlas);
        manager.load(uiSkin);
        manager.load(defaultFont);
        manager.load(mediumFont);
    }

    public static void dispose()
    {
        manager.dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: Just instantiate a new one. Let the GC take the disposed one.

Comment: Can you show us a bit more of your code? `Assets.manager` sounds like something you've initialised yourself.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Ohh I feel so stupid, I just have to `Assets.manager = new AssetManager();` probably, gonna try when back. I really don't know where my head was :).

Comment: Remove every occurrence of the `static` keyword. You might want to read into OOP.

Comment: @Xoppa No I want to access them from anywhere. My app uses like 20 classes and more then 15 use the assets. Instead of passing all of them through each method that need them or create fields to pass them into the constructors I like to have access to them like this.

Comment: @Xoppa besides that every example I could find about the asset manager uses it like this. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx-demo-superjumper/blob/master/core/src/com/badlogicgames/superjumper/Assets.java, I know how I could make this work in a OOP way. But, one should not write OOP for the sake of OOP.

Comment: Android recycles the JVM, causing statics to have a different life-cycle than your app. Your code clearly shows that you're assuming that they have the same life-cycle, which is one of the most common mistake made. OOP makes you think about this life-cycle, saving you a lot of problems later on. Btw, if 75% of your classes need direct access to assets then that might be a sign that you really want to read up on OOP.

Comment: @Xoppa Four screen classes that need the uiSkin and the fonts. A base fruit interface that my 8 fruits implement need access to the sprite = 9. My fruits objects need to act very differently from eachother. Yes I could use a abstract method but again I reach my goal. My player needs a sprite too = 10, it actually uses a body class too that needs a sprite = 11. My effects class = 12. What is the problem with that? I could actually make the same using 2500 classes using insanely deep OOP and passing huge amounts of parameters into my methods. Ever heard of component based design?

Comment: @Xoppa I wasn't really thinking when I posted this question, been at it for too long I guess. But again, one should not write OOP for the sake of OOP. OOP is there to uncomplicate and organize things. You do not have to use it in order to reach your goals.

Comment: I don't know your code, that's why I said *might*. If you think it doesn't fit your needs then that's okay. I'm afraid that this is going beyond the scope of your question and doesnt fit the comments. If you want more help on that then consider posting another question on this site, on the forum or on irc. Anyway, I never said to write OOP for the sake of OOP. I said *to read into it*, to help you think about the code you write, like object life-cycle and responsibilities. I'm the last to say that you should over complicate your design. Btw, a sprite is not an asset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new one every time you call load. Something like this:

```
public static AssetManager manager;

public static void load()
{   
    manager = new AssetManager();
    manager.load(spriteAtlas);
    manager.load(uiAtlas);
    manager.load(uiSkin);
    manager.load(defaultFont);
    manager.load(mediumFont);
}
```